# springboot test @value("${server.port}")

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am so puzzled about this situation when I try to get the server port in the JUnit4 Test,but the result is outof my mind,the result is -1.Can you help me?

the application.properties:

server.port = 30008

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(CustomerCenterApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class BaseTestService {
@Value("${server.port}")
String serverPort;
@Test
public void test(){
System.out.println(serverPort);
}
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)` into your code here.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class BaseTestService {
    ......
}
```

---

The magic is codes here, in your case, match the if condition, so will init with the inline properties.

org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader#getInlinedProperties

```
protected String[] getInlinedProperties(MergedContextConfiguration config) {
    ArrayList<String> properties = new ArrayList<String>();
    // JMX bean names will clash if the same bean is used in multiple contexts
    disableJmx(properties);
    properties.addAll(Arrays.asList(config.getPropertySourceProperties()));
    if (!isEmbeddedWebEnvironment(config) && !hasCustomServerPort(properties)) {
        properties.add("server.port=-1");
    }
    return properties.toArray(new String[properties.size()]);
}
```

Comment: ho ,thanks!,I know it  works well when the version of spring boot is above 1.4.0,but i want know why it can not work and why the server port is -1 in this way

Comment: @xkupc welcome, so you can accept this answer and make your question more useful for other guys too.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with

```
@LocalServerPort
int port;
```

or

```
@Value("${local.server.port}")
int port;
```

Both should do the same.

Source: [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-discover-the-http-port-at-runtime) (73.4 Discover the HTTP port at runtime)

Comment: ho ,thanks!,I know it  works well when the version of spring boot is above 1.4.0,but i want know why it can not work and why the server port is -1 in this way